# Spring-Hibernate - No Session found for current thread

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a java stuts2 web application using spring and hibernate.

Im getting `org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread`.

**SpringBean.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.rohith" />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/company" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource" />
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>

    </bean>
    <!-- <tx:annotation-driven/> -->
    <bean id = "transactionManager" class = "org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name = "sessionFactory" ref = "sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="customerDaoImpl" class="org.rohith.dao.impl.CustomerDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="customerServiceImpl" class="org.rohith.service.impl.CustomerServiceImpl">
        <property name="customerDaoImpl" ref="customerDaoImpl"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
   <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>  
        <!-- Names the annotated entity class -->
        <mapping class="org.rohith.model.Customer"/>    
    </session-factory>  
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**CustomerServiceImpl.java**

```
package org.rohith.service.impl;

import org.rohith.dao.impl.CustomerDaoImpl;
import org.rohith.model.Customer;
import org.rohith.service.CustomerService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerDaoImpl customerDaoImpl;

    @Override
    public void saveCustomer(Customer customer) {
        customerDaoImpl.saveCustomer(customer);
    }
    public CustomerDaoImpl getCustomerDaoImpl() {
        return customerDaoImpl;
    }
    public void setCustomerDaoImpl(CustomerDaoImpl customerDaoImpl) {
        this.customerDaoImpl = customerDaoImpl;
    }

}
```

**CustomerDaoImpl.java**

```
package org.rohith.dao.impl;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.rohith.dao.CustomerDao;
import org.rohith.model.Customer;


public class CustomerDaoImpl   implements CustomerDao {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public void saveCustomer(Customer customer) {
        Session session = getSession();
        session.clear();
        try {
                session.saveOrUpdate(customer);
                session.flush();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return this.sessionFactory;
    }

    public Session getSession() throws HibernateException {
        Session sess = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        if (sess == null) {
            sess = getSessionFactory().openSession();
        }
//      Session sess = getSessionFactory().openSession();
        return sess;
    }

}
```

**CustomerAction.java**

```
public class CustomerAction extends ActionSupport{
    private String name;
    private String addr1;
    private String addr2;
    private String city;
    private String state;

    private CustomerServiceImpl customerServiceImpl;

//Getters and setters

    public String execute(){
        Customer cust= new Customer();
        cust.setName(name);
        cust.setAddress1(addr1);
        cust.setAddress2(addr2);
        cust.setCity(city);
        cust.setState(state);
        System.out.println(name);
        WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext = WebApplicationContextUtils
                .getRequiredWebApplicationContext(getRequest().getSession()
                        .getServletContext());
        customerServiceImpl = (CustomerServiceImpl) webApplicationContext.getBean("customerServiceImpl");
        customerServiceImpl.saveCustomer(cust);
        //saveCust(cust);
        return "success";
    }
protected HttpServletRequest getRequest() {
        return ServletActionContext.getRequest();
    }
protected HttpServletResponse getResponse() {
        return ServletActionContext.getResponse();
    }
}
```

The Exception I am getting

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:97)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:978)
    org.rohith.dao.impl.CustomerDaoImpl.getSession(CustomerDaoImpl.java:33)
    org.rohith.dao.impl.CustomerDaoImpl.saveCustomer(CustomerDaoImpl.java:16)
    org.rohith.service.impl.CustomerServiceImpl.saveCustomer(CustomerServiceImpl.java:18)
    org.rohith.CustomerAction.execute(CustomerAction.java:36)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

Comment: You don't have any transaction handling in your code. Uncomment the `<tx:annotation-driven/>` in the file, and annotate your service with @Transactional. Also, why are you using @Autowired annotations if you define all your beans and properties in the XML? And why do you define an interface for your service and DAO if you never use them?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have a transaction manager specified in your Spring config, but no configuration on when or where to apply transactions.

In your **SpringBean.xml** you should uncomment `<tx:annotation-driven/>`:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

And then you should annotate the `CustomerServiceImpl.saveCustomer` method as `@Transactional`:

```
@Service
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {

    ...

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void saveCustomer(Customer customer) {
        customerDaoImpl.saveCustomer(customer);
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Add the following property in your `hibernate.cfg.xml` file for Hibernate 4.

```
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

Comment: I have one question still

Answer (score 2):

Add @EnableTransactionManagement annotation in your java configuration file if your configuration based on annotation without xml.

This may help someone

Answer (score 1):

```
You can add in hibernate.proerties below value. It's worked for me.

hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext
```

or

hibernate.current_session_context_class=thread