# @Transactional don't work, maybe bad configuration for sessionfactory.getCurrentSession()

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, transactional

I have a spring application when using Hibernate4 all it works with sessionFactory.openSession() in StageDaoImpl:

```
@Repository(value = "stageDao")
public class StageDaoImpl implements StageDao {

  @Autowired
  private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  @Override
  public Integer editStage(Stage stage) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Integer ban = 1;
    try {
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.update(stage);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        ban = -1;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ban = -2;
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return ban;
  }
```

I try to change editStage to @Transactional annotation, but I do not know how to configure transaction, It is always the same result

```
@Repository(value = "stageDao")
public class StageDaoImpl implements StageDao {
  @Autowired
  private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

      @Override
      @Transactional
  public Integer editStage(Stage stage) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Integer ban = 1;
    try {  
        session.update(stage);
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        ban = -1;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ban = -2;
    }
    return ban;
  }
```

Error StackTrace :

```
 org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
```

**sevices-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd">

    <!-- holding properties for database connectivity / -->
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/config/jdbc.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true" order="1" />
    <!-- enabling annotation driven configuration / -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Sesion factory  -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.school.graduation.entities"></property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.InformixDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.use_scrollable_resultset">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- The only thing in here is the driver for hibernate-->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**servlet-context.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans:beans xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
        xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" 
        xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache" 
        xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-3.2.xsd">

        <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

        <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
        <mvc:annotation-driven />

        <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/ by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
        <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

        <beans:bean id="viewResolver1" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver">
            <beans:property name="order" value="1" />
            <beans:property name="basename" value="views"/>
        </beans:bean>

        <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <beans:property name="order" value="1" />
            <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
            <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        </beans:bean>

        <!-- Configure the multipart resolver -->
        <beans:bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
            <beans:property name="maxUploadSize" value="50485760" />
        </beans:bean>

        <context:component-scan base-package="org.school.graduation" />

        <task:annotation-driven />

    </beans:beans>
```

**root-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->
    <import resource="classpath:**/*-config.xml"/>

</beans>
```

**StageStepServiceImpl.java**

```
 @Component
    @Service("stageStepService")
    public class StageStepServiceImpl implements StageStepService {
    @Resource(name="stageDao")
        private StageDao stageDao;

@Override
    public Integer generatingStage( Stage stage ) {
        Integer serviceValue = 0;

        try {
            serviceValue = stageDao.editStage(stage);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            serviceValue = -5;
        }

        return serviceValue;
    }

}
```

**it's a Maven multi module project**

```
graduation-dao
├── src/main/java
│   ├── org.school.graduation.dao.administrator.provider
│   │   └── StageDao.java
│   └── org.school.graduation.dao.administrator.providerImpl 
│       └── StageDaoImpl.java
├── Maven Dependencies
├── JRE System Library
├── src
├── target
└── pom.xml
graduation-services
├── src/main/java
│   ├── org.school.graduation.services.administrator.provider
│   │   └── StageService.java
│   └── org.school.graduation.services.administrator.providerImpl 
│       └── StageServiceImpl.java
├── Maven Dependencies
├── JRE System Library
├── src
├── target
└── pom.xml
graduation-web
├── src/main/java
│   └── org.school.graduation.controller.administrator.provider
│       └── StageController.java  
├── src/main/resources
│   ├── root-context.mxl
│   ├── services-config.mxl
│   └── servlet-context.mxl    
├── Maven Dependencies
├── JRE System Library
├── src
├── target
└── pom.xml
```

Comment: How are you calling your editStage()?

Comment: is this your own `SessionFactory`  class or belongs to `Hibernate` ??

Comment: @Vikrant Kashyap SessionFactory by xml (sevices-config.xml)

Comment: You should move annotation `@Transactional` to your service class `StageStepServiceImpl ` instead of `StageDaoImpl` class before method `editStage `

Comment: @NguaCo same result: No Session found for current thread[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElemen

Comment: I using annotation configuration. I will post my answer.

Comment: @jesseCont what's version of spring framework? You can see more information in the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20716939/spring-hibernate-no-session-found-for-current-thread

Comment: @NguaCon   version: 4.2.1.RELEASE

Comment: @NguaCon You need more information?